# Is it possible to block an amount in Paypal like a credit card

Tags: paypal, credit-card

I am starting a business and I would like to offer Paypal as a payment option, but for my business it is essential to be able to block an amount of money, just like a car rental or a hotel does on a credit card. Would it be possible to block an amount from my users PayPal account and release it or book it for good later?

My business is of course an online service, and I want to do this pragmatically in a Spring based application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Authorization and capture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/).

I haven't used that feature from Paypal, but have used it elsewhere. What you are looking for is usually called **card authorization**, **preauthorization**, or **preauth**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible

PayPal's REST API offer 3 primary ways to ensure you paid for product/services that you give to your customers

- **sale**. Makes an immediate payment so you get paid immediately
- **authorize**. Authorizes a payment for capture later.(this is what you see in a car rental or hotel)
  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/authorize-and-capture-payments/
- **order**. Creates an order. - which gives you the flexibility to
  multiple to do multiple authorizations and captures (these are for
  complex use cases such as when you buy a computer from Dell you would
  be authorized for the desktop, monitor, keyboard at different points
  of time based on availability and then the funds captured when they
  are shipped)